# how to show pageload popup only in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$('.popup').show();
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});

$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});
});
```

here are my javascript code....
jquery plugin:http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/7QA3p/

this popup worked on pageload of every page., but i want only show at the pageload of index.html

Comment: Remove the above code in other pages

Comment: document.URL.indexOf('index') > -1 is this what you're looking for? Not ideal though... - another way is to place a hidden field in you're index.html page, and check if the field exists in your javascript.

Comment: put a specific identifier for your `index` and make a condition if that identifier exists then fire the popup else puff :)

Comment: indent the code appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the page is index.html using the code,

```
 var pagePathName = window.location.href;
if (pagePathName.substring(pagePathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "index.html") {}
```

then you can display or not display the popup, like

```
$(function () {
    var pagePathName = window.location.href;
    if (pagePathName.substring(pagePathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "index.html") {
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition to check:

```
if (document.location.pathname.substr(-11) === "/index.html") {
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a QueryString (used like an identifier) to your URL like the example below:

http://example.com/index.html?pop=1

```
$(function(){
   //check here
   var checkQString = window.location.search;
   if(checkQString.startsWith('?')) {
      alert("Open Pop up here");
   } else {
      alert("no pop up");
   }
});
```